# Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8551: bind Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permi

Tags: go-ethereum

I am new to blockchain and was trying to create two nodes with one bootnode.

bootnode is successfully created

bootnode:

command used in bootnode

---

> bootnode -nodekey ./boot.key -verbosity 7 -addr 127.0.0.1:30301

---

node1 is also running

command used in node 1

---

> geth --networkid 14333 --datadir ./data --bootnodes
> enode://xxxxx@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301 --port 30303 --ipcdisable
> --syncmode 'full' --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain “*” --http.port 8546 --unlock '0xxxxx' --password password.txt --mine console

---

node2

command used for node 2

---

> geth --networkid 14333 --datadir ./data --bootnodes
> enode://xxxxx@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301 --port 30304 --ipcdisable
> --syncmode 'full' --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain “*” --http.port 8547 --unlock 'xxxxx' --password password.txt --mine console

---

is showing the following error

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8551: bind:
> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
> is normally permitted.

Kindly provide a solution to address this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Replace --http.port 8547 to --authrpc.port 8547. It's worked for me.

geth --networkid 14333 --datadir ./data --bootnodes enode://xxxxx@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301 --port 30304 --ipcdisable --syncmode 'full' --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain “*” --authrpc.port 8547 --unlock 'xxxxx' --password password.txt --mine console

Answer (score 2):

If you run geth --help

you will see that 8551 is the default port of --authrpc.port

--authrpc.port value           (default: 8551)

So you could specify a different --authrpc.port for node 1 to node 3

Answer (score 0):

Just add --authrpc.port 8553 to the command.

Comment: If you are answering an old question you have to be more clear than existing answers. Can you explain the reason behind using that command line? Do you know what it does?